# Full Calendar selected slot unselect automatically while copying and event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, contextmenu

I am using a jquery context menu with jquery full-calendar to copy and paste events. when I select a slot to copy the event it gets unselected automatically. It happens only when I copy the event using the context menu.
In the context menu there are three options copy, paste and delete.
In jquery full-calendar select function I'm doing add event on double click of slot and copy selected events from a resource to another resource.
here is my context menu code.

```
$i(function () {
        $i.contextMenu({
            selector: '.fc-timeline-event, .fc-highlight',
            callback: function (key, options) {
                if (key == "copy" && options.$trigger[0].classList[0] == "fc-timeline-event") {
                    ContextEventId = options.$trigger[0].id;
                }
                else if (key == "paste" && options.$trigger[0].classList[0] == "fc-highlight") {
                    var resourceA = calendar.getResourceById(ContextSlotSelected.resource.id);
                    var allEvents = resourceA.getEvents();
                    var existed = false;
                    var PasteEvent = calendar.getEventById(ContextEventId);
                    if (PasteEvent != null) {
                        var eventStartTime = new Date(ContextSlotSelected.start);
                        //calculate the endtime of copied event
                        var hourDifference = PasteEvent.end.getHours() - PasteEvent.start.getHours();
                        var minDifference = PasteEvent.end.getMinutes() - PasteEvent.start.getMinutes();
                        var eventEndTime = new Date(ContextSlotSelected.start.setHours(ContextSlotSelected.start.getHours() + hourDifference));
                        eventEndTime.setMinutes(eventEndTime.getMinutes() + minDifference);                       var today = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
                        existed = isAnOverlapEventContext(allEvents, eventStartTime, eventEndTime);
                        if (eventEndTime.getDay() > eventStartTime.getDay()) {
                        }
                        else {
                            if (existed == false) {
                                calendar.addEvent({
                                    id: makeid(5),
                                    title: '',
                                    start: eventStartTime,
                                    end: eventEndTime,
                                    resourceId: ContextSlotSelected.resource.id,
                                    editable: true,
                                    backgroundColor: "lightgreen",
                                    creationDate: today,
                                    SlotType: '2',
                                    constraint: {
                                        resourceIds: [ContextSlotSelected.resource.id]
                                    }
                                });
                                selected = [];
                                isSelected = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    calendar.unselect();
                }
                else if (key == "delete" && options.$trigger[0].classList[0] == "fc-timeline-event") {
                    var DeleteEventID = options.$trigger[0].id;
                    var DeleteEvent = calendar.getEventById(DeleteEventID);
                    if (DeleteEvent != null) {
                        DeleteEvent.remove();
                        ContextEventId = "";
                    }
                    selected = [];
                    isSelected = false;
                }
            },
            items: {
                "copy": { name: "Copy", icon: "copy" },
                "paste": { name: "Paste", icon: "paste" },
                "delete": { name: "Delete", icon: "delete" }
            }
        });
    });
```

[Here is the gif image for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYYet.gif)

Comment: Ok so what's the question / problem? You've described a whole lot of stuff, but it's unclear which part you're unhappy with, or how you want it to work instead, or what steps you've taken to attempt to alter it.

Comment: @ADyson when I copy the event using context menu and select the slot it automatically gets unselected. I have to click again to select the slot. I want to select the slot when I click it for the first time. 

Sorry for the late response.